# Retrieve full url using Scrapy and Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to crawl a webpage. I'm interested in recovering a "complex" URL in this source code :

```
<a href="/searchresults.ja.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAQoggJCEHNlYXJjaF_lpKfpmKrluIJIFVgEaE2IAQGYARW4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AqXw-usFwAIB&sid=99d1716767a9d25ee820122238489b00&tmpl=searchresults&checkin_year_month_monthday=2019-10-15&checkout_year_month_monthday=2019-10-16&city=-240905&class_interval=1&dest_id=-240905&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&srpvid=87de9c92c893006c&ss=%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%B8%82&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&top_ufis=1&rows=20&offset=20" data-page-next class="bui-pagination__link paging-next ga_sr_gotopage_2_85" title="次のページ">
```

The xpath command I use is :

```
next_page = response.xpath('//a[starts-with(@class,"bui-pagination__link paging-next")]/@href').extract()
```

However, I get only  "/searchresults.ja.html" ==> Everything after the ".html" is dumped. I'm not interested in recovering the domain name, but the complex part after the ".hmtl?"

What I would like to have is

> /searchresults.ja.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAQoggJCEHNlYXJjaF_lpKfpmKrluIJIFVgEaE2IAQGYARW4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AqXw-usFwAIB&sid=99d1716767a9d25ee820122238489b00&tmpl=searchresults&checkin_year_month_monthday=2019-10-15&checkout_year_month_monthday=2019-10-16&city=-240905&class_interval=1&dest_id=-240905&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&srpvid=87de9c92c893006c&ss=%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%B8%82&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&top_ufis=1&rows=20&offset=20

Do you know what I should do ?

By the way the page is [this one](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAQoggJCEHNlYXJjaF_lpKfpmKrluIJIFVgEaE2IAQGYARW4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AqXw-usFwAIB&sid=99d1716767a9d25ee820122238489b00&tmpl=searchresults&checkin_year_month_monthday=2019-10-15&checkout_year_month_monthday=2019-10-16&city=-240905&class_interval=1&dest_id=-240905&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&lang=en-gb&no_rooms=1&offset=0&postcard=0&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&soz=1&srpvid=87de9c92c893006c&ss=%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%B8%82&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&top_ufis=1&lang_click=top&cdl=ja&lang_changed=1&nflt=), and I'm trying to get the "next page" of results, at the bottom

Comment: looks like that part after ? is being generated by JS, try to disable JS in your browser and look at that link,

Comment: @Umair when I disable JS for this page, the link is still generated.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1):

The website is using JavaScript to render the next URL. The easiest way to check whether you can scrape anything directly without using JavaScript is using `scrapy shell 'website'` in your terminal (navigate to the directory where your scrapy spider is using the terminal and then execute the command. [Check this image for execution of scrapy shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTcwH.png)

This will open the response of the website in your terminal. Then you can type commands and check what the response is. In your case, the command will be:

```
response.css(".bui-pagination__item.sr_pagination_item a").getall()
```

Or

```
response.css(".bui-pagination__item.bui-pagination__next-arrow a::attr(href)").getall()
```

As you can see, the links are not complete as per your reference in the question. Hence, this proves that the link you're trying to extract cannot be extracted using the straightforward method. You can use Splash (for JS rendering) or manually inspect the request and then duplicate the request using the Request module in scrapy.